# Which windows API call when the user change password? what the good way to hook this API?

Tags: c++, windows, authentication, winapi, hook

I want to know when user try to change his password, and even hook this function.

I know there is [GINA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication) option, and that was replaced from Vista to [ICredentialProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776042(VS.85).aspx).
But at these two, I didn't find a specific API that will called anyway, or one function for every method, that will called when the user change his password.
I think implement DLL proxy for the specific API (after I will find it), there is any better way to implement this hook, to catch the change password user and modify it?

In Addition, at my research I found the function 
**ChangeAccountPassword**.

And also reference to **SpInitialize** function with maybe relevant parameter:

```
typedef struct SECPKG_FUNCTION_TABLE {
...
SpSetExtendedInformationFn       *SpChangeAccountPasswordFn;
...
};
```

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Would help if you added a language tag to your question. But anyway, you want to hook into password changes? That doesn't sound overly secure.

Comment: You are really trying too hard. Why even retrieve the password, when you could enter any password you like ([Silly debugger tricks: Using KD to reset a forgotten administrator password](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=136)).

Comment: What's the point? If you want to know when users change their passwords, use event logs. Control how/when users change their passwords with a group policy. There is no conceivable reason to hook this API.

Comment: [Password Filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721882.aspx). No need to hook anything. Not to mention that allowing a hook to be set would allow anyone at your process' security level to snoop on all the password changes on the system. You'd blow the door off the airtight hatchway.

Answer (score 1):

yes, SpChangeAccountPasswordFn really called in LSASS.EXE . this routine usually call

```
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
SamChangePasswordUser2(IN PUNICODE_STRING ServerName,
                       IN PUNICODE_STRING UserName,
                       IN PUNICODE_STRING OldPassword,
                       IN PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword);
```

from samlib.dll (this is exported function). but most common and interesting point to hook :

```
BOOLEAN NTAPI LsaINotifyPasswordChanged(
  IN PVOID OPTIONAL, 
  IN PUNICODE_STRING ServerName,
  IN PUNICODE_STRING UserName,
  PVOID OPTIONAL,
  PVOID OPTIONAL,
  IN PUNICODE_STRING OldPassword,
  IN PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword);
```

this function is exported from lsasrv.dll and usually called from SpChangeAccountPasswordFn. it present from xp up to latest win10. but signature in xp another than in later versions (1 param shifted to 7 place)